# Imprimir un valor de un ArrayList que esta Dentro de un ArrayLista - java

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un ArrayList que guarda ciertos objetos, pero uno de ellos es un ArrayList, la cuestion es la siguiente necestio mostrar un un Jtable los nombres de las personas y la mayor venta que ha realizado el problema es que las ventas estan guardadas en un Arraylist

este es mi codigo, me muestra los vendedores pero al calcular mayor venta me muestra la misma en todas

```
public void mayorVenta(){

        String matriz[][] = new String[vendedor.size()][3];
        double v ;
        for (int i = 0; i < vendedor.size(); i++) {

            matriz[i][0] = vendedor.get(i).getCodigo();
            matriz[i][1] = vendedor.get(i).getNombre()+" "+vendedor.get(i).getApellido();


            for (int j = 0; j < vendedor.get(i).getVenta().size(); j++){

                v = vendedor.get(i).getVenta().get(0).getValor_venta();
                if(v < vendedor.get(i).getVenta().get(j).getValor_venta()){
                     v= vendedor.get(i).getVenta().get(j).getValor_venta();
                }

                matriz[i][2] = Double.toString(v);
            }

        }
        tablaVendedores1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                matriz,
                new String[]{
                    "Codigo","Nombre", "Mayor ventas Realizada"
                }
        ));
    }
```

Para resumir un poco los Arraylist y Como para tener idea que guardan cada Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<Vendedor> vendedor = new ArrayList<Vendedor>();
vendedor.add(new Vendedor("Codigo", "Nombre" ,ventas));

ArrayList<Ventas> ventas  = new ArrayList<Ventas>();
ventas.add(new Ventas("producto", valorVenta, fecha);
```

Comment: Dentro del segundo for siempre inicializas tu valor de `v` justo en esta linea `v = vendedor.get(i).getVenta().get(0).getValor_venta();` y esta otra linea debería estar fuera del segundo for `matriz[i][2] = Double.toString(v);`

Answer (score 1):

Te lo voy a plantear a mi manera a ver si te vale.

Obtenemos una **lista** con todos los vendedores..

```
List<Vendedor> vendedores = misVendedores();
```

Declaramos una variable de tipo `double` en mi caso, donde guardaremos el **valor** de la **mayor venta** del vendedor.

```
double mayorVenta = 0;
```

Y una variable **`i`** para iterar por los índices de los distintos vendedores.

```
int i = 0;
```

---

Ahora **recorremos** los diferentes **vendedores** con un for mejorado 'for each'..

```
for (Vendedor vendedor : vendedores) {

}
```

Y de cada una de sus **ventas** obtenemos el de mayor valor..

```
for (Vendedor vendedor : vendedores) {
     for (Ventas v : vendedores.get(i).getVentas()) {
            if (v.getValorVenta() > mayorVenta) mayorVenta = v.getValorVenta();
     }
     i++;
     System.out.println("Vendedor: " + vendedor.getNombre() + ", y su mayor venta es: " + mayorVenta);  

}
```

---

```
List<Vendedor> vendedores = misVendedores();
        double mayorVenta = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (Vendedor vendedor : vendedores) {
            for (Ventas v : vendedores.get(i).getVentas()) {
                if (v.getValorVenta() > mayorVenta) mayorVenta = v.getValorVenta();
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("Vendedor: " + vendedor.getNombre() + ", y su mayor venta es: " + mayorVenta);
        }
```

**Y un resultado de los planteado podría ser este**

```
Vendedor: Fermin, y su mayor venta es: 50.0
Vendedor: Antonio, y su mayor venta es: 80.0
```

Comment: ya que utilizas el For Each, puedes usar vendedor en lugar de vendedores.get(i), ahorrandote el uso de i directamente.

Comment: Toda la razón compañero. Más fácil y sin complicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Usando Java 8 o superior y partir de un Vendedor:

```
public class Vendedor{
    ...
        public double getMayorVenta(Vendedor vendedor){
            return vendedor.getVentas()
                  .stream()//Obtiene un Stream sobre la lista para operar sobre ella
                  .map(Ventas::getValorVenta) //Mapea el contenido del stream de Ventas (del List original) a Double, en base al método getValorVenta
                  .max();//Del conjunto de valores del Stream (ahora mismo Doubles con el valorVenta) se obtiene el valor superior
        }
...
}
```

Con este método obtendrías de manera sencilla la mayor venta de cada vendedor.

```
double mayorVenta = vendedor.getMayorVenta();
```